# Using open source XACML implementations for simulating a PDP, PEP and PAP

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, alfa

I am working on a ABAC  project and  am using ALFA plug-in in eclipse to to write the policies and am enforcing the same through a java program. Instead of that I want to make use of the open source XACML implementations available to simulate a PDP,PAP and PEP. How to solve the issue ?

Comment: Are you looking for open-source? Try WSO2 or SunXACML. Alternatively you can request to download an evaluation of the Axiomatics Policy Server Express Edition. http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products/authorization-for-applications/axiomatics-policy-server-express-edition.html

Comment: Have a look at [HERAS^AF](https://bitbucket.org/herasaf/herasaf-xacml-core).

Comment: Could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Open source XACML 3.0 implementations:

- [AuthzForce](https://github.com/authzforce/)
- [WSO2 Balana](https://github.com/wso2/balana)
- (EDIT based on David's comment:) [AT&T XACML](https://github.com/att/XACML).

More info on the [XACML wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML#XACML_Implementations).

(Heras-AF and SunXACML are XACML 2.0 only.)

Comment: And AT&T XACML.